# Javascript (pure) select first element (table)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two tables like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

They are all same. I have to select the first one (and the second) using pure javascript.
In jQuery it is `$(table:first)`.

If tables were like this (with classes) could I use `getElementByClassName('class')[0]`

```
<table class="class">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="class">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: We need more information about the mark up to identify the tables correctly i.e. is there a container around it? Are those tables always the first and second tables on the page?

Comment: see your soluttion below using pure javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`.getElementsByTagName("table")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) on the `document`, which will return a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList) containing all tables within the document. NodeLists are array-like objects and the tables are returned in the same order as they have in the document, so you could then just take the first element using its index.

```
var firstTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
```

**NodeLists are *live***

It is worth noting that the `NodeList` returned by `.getElementsByTagName()` is *live*, meaning that if you do DOM-manipulations after your call to `.getElementsByTagName()`, those manipulations will be reflected in your list.

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
var firstTableBefore = tables[0];

/*
If you then prepend a new table to the body at this point, calling tables[0] 
again will now return the newly added element
*/

var firstTableAfter = tables[0];

// firstTableBefore and firstTableAfter will NOT be the same
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

`var firstTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]`

which is cross-browser compatible.

For newer browsers you could use:

`var firstTable = document.querySelector("table")`

which will select the first table.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [getElementsByTagName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp) to get the tables collection and use 0 index for first table.

```
firstTable = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
```

Comment: `table` was not in quotes. Removed it now.

Answer (score 3):

[`getElementsByTagName` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) returns a `NodeList` which is an array-like object. The elements are returned in document order. You can simply access each element by its index:

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
// first table: tables[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get an array of the  elements on your page by using:

```
var tables= document.getElementsByTagName("table");
```

Then

```
tables[0]
```

will give you the first table.

Answer (score 2):

In your modify as following:

```
<table id="first">
  <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="second">
  <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In your js code:

```
var table1=document.getElementByID("first");
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code for your solution

```
<html> 
 <head><title>hello</title>
 </head>
 <body>

     <table> 
        <tr>
             <td>click first td(table1)</td></br>
             <td>click second td(table1)</td></br>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table> 
        <tr>
             <td>first td(table2)</td></br>
             <td>second td(table2)</td></br>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
            var firstTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
            //alert(firstTable)

                cells = firstTable.getElementsByTagName('td');

                for (var i=0,len=cells.length; i<len; i++){
                    cells[i].onclick = function(){
                        alert(this.innerHTML);
                    }
                }
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the first table by `tag`, you can simply do this:

```
var first = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
```

To get the first table by `class`, you can simply do this:

```
var first = document.getElementsByClassName("class")[0];
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zJLVt/)

Answer (score 1):

Using pure js, you can get elements using the different document.getelement commands. What you're looking for here is

```
document.getElementsByTagName("table")
```

This will return an array, and you can do your work from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `document.getElementsByTagName` javascript call.

For your HTML as above:

```
var allTables = document.getElementsByTagName("table")
alert(allTables.length);
```

alerts me 2.

Then you can access `allTables[0]` etc...

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do the same.

```js
let firstTable = document.querySelectorAll("table")[0];
let secondTable = document.querySelectorAll("table")[1];
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>first td(table1)</td>
    <td>second td(table1)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>first td(table2)</td>
    <td>second td(table2)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```